# How can I determine an application's software prerequisites?

Tags: winforms, prerequisites

I'm developing a small WinForms program for home use - I have no intentions to releasing it anywhere.

Running it on my development machine, where I have Visual Studio and .NET and whatever else installed, works but deploying it on my PC, where I might not have all those frameworks, doesn't. I'm using some library written in C++ so I'm assuming I'm going to need some version of Visual C++ Redistributable, but I'm not sure which? And I'm not sure if that would be all. So, how can I determine an application's software prerequisites?

I used Dependency Walker and I got a message `IEHIMS.DLL - Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2)`, but that's all I could make out; there is so much information I'm having trouble make sense of it all. Besides, according to a quick google, `IESHIMS.DLL` has something to do with Internet Explorer, so it shouldn't really matter.

Thanks in advance to anyone taking to the time to consider my question.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

For framework you can set the prerequisites for your application by going to project properties -> Publish -> Prerequisites. So now, if the required framework is not installed on the deployment machine, the setup will prompt for an install.

Now, for other dlls you are using, copy those dlls to your bin folder of the project and add the files while creating setup. This will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice about the prerequisites; I appreciate the time you took and I'm sure that'll come in handy some day.

It turned out, however, that the problem lie somewhere else completely; I apologize.